# Spark streaming: Output Op Duration is greater than job duration

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-emr

I am running a spark streaming application on EMR.

I notice on the console, `Output Op Duration` is orders of magnitude higher than actual `Job Duration`.

What is Spark doing `Output Op Duration` - `Job Duration` = `delta`?

here `delta` is ~2.5 minutes which is unacceptable

[image: Spark Streaming console]

Comment: got the exact same issue, any update on this?